# Python, PyVISA, and string encoding

Tags: python, encoding, io, visa

I'm trying to control a device over the network in Python 3.4 using PyVISA and the SCPI protocol. I've been able to establish a connection, and read and write data to and from the device. For instance, the simple program

```
import visa
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
device = rm.open_resource('resource_address')
print(device.query('*IDN?\n'))
```

has the expected output.

I would like to send this device some more complicated commands, specifically I'd like it to save the data it has recorded. According to the manual I should send something like

```
device.write(':MMEMory:STORe:TRACe TRACE1,E:\filename.csv\n')
```

This does result in the saving of some file, but the device itself does not recognize it, and neither does a computer. Sending the command using the basic I/O utility that comes with the National Instruments software that I used to set up this device works fine (and so does the I/O functionality of the proprietary software of the device's manufacturer). From this I would guess that there's something wrong with the way Python encodes/formats my command string, but I haven't been able to figure this out.

Comment: Notice your string has a `\f` character in it. You'll need to escape the backslash, so use `E:\\filename.csv`

Comment: Although I was just using this as an example, that's a useful thing to keep in mind. Thank you!

Comment: Alternatively, rather than escaping the backslashes, use a raw string: `r':MMEMory:STORe:TRACe TRACE1,E:\filename.csv' + '\n'`. Are you doing this in Python 2 or Python 3? Is the version you're using the same as what the manual's using? If you're using Python 3 you _may_ need to send byte strings; the default string type in Python 3 is Unicode.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.4. I've tried sending byte strings (by prepending a b to my string), but this didn't work (neither did turning it into a raw string). This had no effect on the device, which I'm guessing means that it wasn't formatted correctly. Incidentally, sending simpler commands (without backslashes such as in my example) works fine.

Comment: I solved my problem by using byte literal strings, which can be written using `device.write_raw()` in PyVISA.